# Building google api c++ sdk gets stuck

Tags: c++, build, google-api

I have been trying to build core C++ SDK to use Google APIs as directed here https://github.com/google/google-api-cpp-client, everything builds up until it gets stuck here:

```
`
-- Looking for elf.h - found
-- Looking for a Fortran compiler
-- Looking for a Fortran compiler - /usr/bin/f95
`
```

Has anyone successfully gone through the install?

Comment: I am building the sdk with google gmail api c++ library, is there other available resources for getting this done.